# i want to plot the googlemap from these lat long recving within for loop?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
for (int j = 0; j < msgObject.length(); j++) {

    JSONObject d = msgObject.getJSONObject(j);


    Startlongitude = d.getString("SfltLogitude");
    Startlattitude = d.getString("Sfltlattitude");
    Endlongitude = d.getString("EfltLogitude");
    Endlattitude = d.getString("Efltlattitude");
    Eat = Double.parseDouble(Endlattitude);
    Elot = Double.parseDouble(Endlongitude);

    lat = Double.parseDouble(Startlattitude);
    lon = Double.parseDouble(Startlongitude);
    latlon = new LatLng(lat, lon);
    latlon2 = new LatLng(Eat, Elot);
}
break;
```

these are lat long i am recving from Server ,have parse into double..but now i dont know how to plot the Google map?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a div called map and then call the initMap method on document load.

You can move the json for loop to another method in case you don't have the data when the page is loaded.

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng
        });


for(int j=0;j < *array length*; j++)

               JSONObject d=msgObject.getJSONObject(j);


               Startlongitude=d.getString("SfltLogitude");
               Startlattitude=d.getString("Sfltlattitude");
               Endlongitude = d.getString("EfltLogitude");
               Endlattitude = d.getString("Efltlattitude");
               Elat=Double.parseDouble(Endlattitude);
               Elot=Double.parseDouble(Endlongitude);

               lat=Double.parseDouble(Startlattitude);
              lon=Double.parseDouble(Startlongitude);


         var startLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lon};
         var endLatLng = {lat: Elat, lng: Elot};

         var startmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: startLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Start Marker'+j
         });

         var endmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: endLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'End Marker'+j
         });
      }
}
```

Comment: This looks like you're mixing javascript with Java